# Does `import` incur a runtime burden in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

Is there a reason to avoid localized imports?

Since I'm pretty new to Python, I don't have a good intuition about good and bad practices, other than those my editor PyCharm suggests.

One thing that I've been doing is localizing `import` statements such as the code shown below.  I am supposing that such an `import` is only a message to the compiler, and not to the runtime, and that it insures no additional run-time overhead.  If there is a run-time overhead, it might be better if I move the `from ... import...` out of the function definition up to the top level.

```
def conversion8(self):
    from genus_types import notp
    for a in self.tds:
        for n in self.tds:
            if notp(n) and self.annihilator(a, n.s):
                return self.zero()
    return self
```

Comment: Note that ``import`` *is* a runtime statement. There are almost no static declarations in Python.

Comment: [from PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports): _Imports are always put at the top of the file, just after any module comments and docstrings, and before module globals and constants._

Comment: Imports should go into the top part of the file. Unless there is a good reason to do a local import. Preventing a circular import might be such a reason.

Comment: I tried moving all imports to top level, and I had lots of circularity problems, so I reverted my changes.  Sounds like I still need to move up the ones that don't cause problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, imports incur a runtime cost. In many cases it is negligible, but not necessarily. Suppose you have the following `__init__.py`:

```
import time

time.sleep(60)
```

By importing this module, you're necessarily incurring a 60 second runtime cost. While this specific case isn't realistic, other things like it might be (initializing expensive resources, connections, etc.)

For this reason (among others like circular or non-portable imports), sometimes local imports are preferable. Unless you have a good reason to localize the import, I recommend following PEP8.

Answer (score 4):

The [`import` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement) is executed at runtime. It has two different purposes:

- load the target module into the module cache *if it is not loaded already*
- name-bind the requested objects from the module into the current scope

So whenever an `import` is encountered during normal execution, there is a run-time overhead. However, the significant overhead of loading the module is usually incurred only the first time.

Since the module cache is accessible (via `sys.modules`) it is in principle possible that a module is evicted from the cache and loaded more than once. For usual modules, this does not occur in practice.

Moving imports to functions is usually done to conditionally import modules only when needed, or to break cyclic imports. Unless this is actually needed, [it is idiomatic to place imports at the top of modules](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports).